# Adding missing rows from one dataframe to another based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My sample data is below:

```
data1 = {'index':  ['001', '001', '001', '002', '002', '003', '004','004'],
        'type' : ['red', 'red', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue'],
        'class' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame (data1, columns = ['index', 'type', 'class']) 
df1
    index   type    class
0   001     red     A
1   001     red     A
2   001     red     A
3   002     yellow  A
4   002     red     A
5   003     green   A
6   004     blue    A
7   004     blue    A

data2 = {'index':  ['001', '001', '002', '003', '004'],
        'type' : ['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'],
        'class' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
        'outcome': ['in', 'in', 'out', 'in', 'out']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame (data2, columns = ['index', 'type', 'class', 'outcome']) 
df2
    index   type    class   outcome
0   001     red     A       in
1   001     red     A       in
2   002     yellow  A       out
3   003     green   B       in
4   004     blue    A       out
```

In `df1`, the `class = A`, in `df2` it can be `A`, `B` or `C`. I want to add the missing rows in `df2` from `df1`. `df1` has the counts of types for each index. For example if in `df1` index `001` appears 3 times it means I should also have it 3 times in `df2`. For rows from `df1` that are not in `df2`, column `outcome` should equal NaN. OUTPUT should be:

```
    index   type    class   outcome
0   001     red     A       in
1   001     red     A       in
2   001     red     A       NaN
3   002     yellow  A       out
4   002     red     A       NaN
5   003     green   A       NaN
6   003     green   B       in
7   004     blue    A       out
8   004     blue    A       NaN
```

I tried with pd.concat and pd.merge but I kept getting duplicates or wrong rows added. Does someone have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter values for uniqueness, so possible use outer join by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) in next step:

```
df1['group'] = df1.groupby(['index','type','class']).cumcount()
df2['group'] = df2.groupby(['index','type','class']).cumcount()

df = (df1.merge(df2, on=['index','type','class','group'], how='outer')
         .sort_values(by=['index', 'class'])
         .drop(columns='group'))
print (df)
  index    type class outcome
0   001     red     A      in
1   001     red     A      in
2   001     red     A     NaN
3   002  yellow     A     out
4   002     red     A     NaN
5   003   green     A     NaN
8   003   green     B      in
6   004    blue     A     out
7   004    blue     A     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1['index_id'] = df1.groupby('index').cumcount()
df2['index_id'] = df2.groupby('index').cumcount()

merged = (
    df2
    .merge(df1, how='outer', on=['index', 'type', 'class', 'index_id'])
    .sort_values(by=['index', 'class'])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .drop(columns='index_id')
)

print(merged)
    index   type  class outcome
0   001     red    A    in
1   001     red    A    in
2   001     red    A    NaN
3   002     yellow A    out
4   002     red    A    NaN
5   003     green  A    NaN
6   003     green  B    in
7   004     blue   A    out
8   004     blue   A    NaN
```